# How to write custom chaining

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I want to create custom chainig to prevent some repetition.

I am a bit unclear on how to define it

I have a lot of :

```
   someLiveData.observe(this) { objectWithTextAndVisibility->
    textView.text = objectWithTextAndVisibility.text
    textView.visibility = objectWithTextAndVisibility.visibility
   }
```

i want to write something that will look as follows

```
someLiveData.observe(this).bind(textView).on(text)
```

and it will do the same thing
is there a way to define this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, a generic structure like this may achieve what you want to do:

```
infix fun <T> LiveData<T>.observe(owner: LifecycleOwner) = LiveDataHolder(this, owner)

class LiveDataHolder<T>(val liveData: LiveData<T>, val owner: LifecycleOwner)

infix fun <T, S> LiveDataHolder<T>.bind(subject: S) = LiveDataBinder(this, subject)

class LiveDataBinder<T, S>(val liveDataHolder: LiveDataHolder<T>, val subject: S)
```

```
infix fun <T : VisibilityCarrier> LiveDataBinder<T, TextView>.on(textSelector: (T) -> String) {
    liveDataHolder.liveData.observe(liveDataHolder.owner) {
        subject.text = textSelector(it)
        subject.visibility = it.visibility
    }
}

interface VisibilityCarrier {
    val visibility: Int
}
```

This should give you good flexibility and prevent a lot of repetition, however at the cost of adding some obscurity to your code base, and not conveying what it does right alway.

Additional and different behaviors can be added by implementing new `LiveDataBinder` extension functions, like the `on` function, even for different kinds of objects and expected interfaces (instead of only this combination of `TextView` and `VisibilityCarrier`, even by maintaining the `on` name) and so on.

The use style can vary a lot with this, being like the ones below (considering `Data` implements `VisibilityCarrier` interface and provides a `text` `String` property):

```
liveData.observe(this).bind(textView).on { it.text }
liveData.observe(this) bind textView on { it.text }
liveData.observe(this).bind(textView).on(Data::text)
liveData.observe(this) bind textView on Data::text
```

This `on` implementation also allows for defining which property to use as text and different classes as well, like so:

```
anotherLiveData.observe(this).bind(textView).on(AnotherData::someText)
anotherLiveData.observe(this).bind(textView).on(AnotherData::anotherText)
```

**UPDATE:** After reading the explanation in the comments I think I got it, and believe this should address the point (where `Data` contains `text` and `visibility` properties):

```
infix fun <T : Data, S : View> LiveDataBinder<T, out S>.on(textProperty: KMutableProperty1<S, in String>) {
    liveDataHolder.liveData.observe(liveDataHolder.owner) {
        textProperty.set(subject, it.text)
        subject.visibility = it.visibility
    }
}
```

In the case of `TextView` and other Java defined classes, compiler will complain about synthetic access, and this problem could be addressed like in the following snippet (Kotlin views should be fine without this kind of workaround):

```
var TextView.text_: CharSequence
    get() = text
    set(value) { text = value }
```

And the usage would be like:

```
liveData.observe(this).bind(textView).on(TextView::text_)
liveData.observe(this).bind(customView).on(CustomView::someText)
```

**UPDATE 2:** A better approach as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66414161/how-to-write-custom-chaining/66415077#comment117417054_66415077) by [Tenfour04](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506796/tenfour04) (thanks). The following will avoid the synthetic property access compiler error:

```
infix fun <T : Data, S : View> LiveDataBinder<T, S>.on(textProperty: S.(String) -> Unit) {
    liveDataHolder.liveData.observe(liveDataHolder.owner) {
        subject.textProperty(it.text)
        subject.visibility = it.visibility
    }
}
```

And the usage would be like (without needing the `text_` property extension):

```
liveData.observe(owner).bind(textView).on(TextView::setText)
```

Comment: a bit not exactly what i meant. I wanted "textView.text" to be in the on clause, i have custom views and some of the views are not textviews and they have other properties that need to be watched, and so i wanted to specify the recepient of the action and the selector it was meant to invoke

Comment: Updated the answer with a possible solution for this kind of problem.
Wish it helps 

Comment: Other ways i can think of doing it is by using reflection, however maybe some other issues could arise by going down this route 

Comment: I also believe the `LiveDataHolder` and `LiveDataBinder` could be unified with a bit of more elaborated work on the "DSL definition", reducing the size of the generic structure, but I think this way the information flow and the working principle stays a little more visible and easier to understand.

Comment: Instead of KMutableProperty, why not define it as `S.(String)->Unit`? Then I don’t think you have to worry about the synthetic access thing.

Comment: I've had to mix and match both your answers to get what I need. The part about .on() is still not clear to me, because i write the method that should be invoked in the on clause but it's not invoked

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments on the other answer, I think I see what you're trying to do.

If I'm correct, you want to use the builder pattern to first bind something that is set (a setter), and then specify a getter/mapper of the data type to get some sub-data type that is applied with that setter.

So you can set up a couple of intermediate classes to do it like this:

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observe(owner: LifecycleOwner) = BindableObserver<T>().also { observe(owner, it) }

class BindableObserver<D>: Observer<D> {
    private var boundSetter: BoundSetter<D, *>? = null

    fun <S> bind(setter: (S)->Unit) = BoundSetter<D, S>(setter).also { boundSetter = it }

    override fun onChanged(t: D) {
        boundSetter?.execute(t)
    }
}

class BoundSetter<D, S>(private val setter: (S)->Unit) {
    private var dataGetter: ((D)->S)? = null

    fun on(getter: (D)->S) {
        dataGetter = getter
    }

    fun execute(newValue: D) {
        val subData = dataGetter?.invoke(newValue) ?: return
        setter.invoke(subData)
    }
}
```

You can't simply pass a TextView to bind, because Kotlin won't know which property of TextView to set, so you pass the property using property syntax (`::`). Unfortunately, TextView has a bunch of `setText()` overloads, so you have to specify the input type as well.

Usage syntax would be like this:

```
someLiveData.observe(this)
    .bind<String>(textView::setText)
    .on(ObjectWithTextAndVisibility::text)
```

To avoid the need for specifying which function of a TextView to bind, you could add a helper function:

```
fun <D> BindableObserver<D>.bind(textView: TextView) = bind<String>(textView::setText)
```

and then usage would be closer to what you suggested:

```
someLiveData.observe(this)
    .bind(textView)
    .on(ObjectWithTextAndVisibility::text)
```

You could also use lambda syntax:

```
someLiveData.observe(this)
    .bind(textView)
    .on { it.text }
```